# Using dopri5 to plot a system of ODEs in matrix form

Tags: python, matrix, ode

The system of equations I'm interested in plotting is the following:

[image]

I was able to plot them modifying an example someone posted by doing the following:

```
import scipy as sp
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

#Constants
c13 = 4.2
c14 = 4.2
c21 = 4.3
c32 = 4.4
c34 = 4.4
c42 = 4.4
c43 = 4.4

e12 = 1.9
e23 = 2.5
e24 = 2.2
e31 = 2.0
e41 = 2.0

#Time
t_end = 700
t_start = 0
t_step = 1
t_interval = sp.arange(t_start, t_end, t_step)

#Initial Condition
r = [0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5]

def model(t,r):
    Eqs= np.zeros((4))
    Eqs[0] = (r[0]*(1-r[0]*r[0]-r[1]*r[1]-r[2]*r[2]-r[3]*r[3])-c21*((r[1]*r[1])*r[0])+e31*((r[2]*r[2])*r[0])+e41*((r[3]*r[3])*r[0]))
    Eqs[1] = (r[1]*(1-r[0]*r[0]-r[1]*r[1]-r[2]*r[2]-r[3]*r[3])+e12*((r[0]*r[0])*r[1])-c32*((r[2]*r[2])*r[1])-c42*((r[3]*r[3])*r[1]))
    Eqs[2] = (r[2]*(1-r[0]*r[0]-r[1]*r[1]-r[2]*r[2]-r[3]*r[3])-c13*((r[0]*r[0])*r[2])+e23*((r[1]*r[1])*r[2])-c43*((r[3]*r[3])*r[2]))
    Eqs[3] = (r[3]*(1-r[0]*r[0]-r[1]*r[1]-r[2]*r[2]-r[3]*r[3])-c14*((r[0]*r[0])*r[3])+e24*((r[1]*r[1])*r[3])-c34*((r[2]*r[2])*r[3]))
    return Eqs

ode =  spi.ode(model)

ode.set_integrator('dopri5')
ode.set_initial_value(r,t_start)
ts = []
ys = []

while ode.successful() and ode.t < t_end:
    ode.integrate(ode.t + t_step)
    ts.append(ode.t)
    ys.append(ode.y)

t = np.vstack(ts)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = np.vstack(ys).T

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, x1, 'r', label = 'x1')
plt.plot(t, x2, 'b', label = 'x2')
plt.plot(t, x3, 'g', label = 'x3')
plt.plot(t, x4, 'purple', label = 'x4')
plt.xlim([0,t_end])
plt.legend()
plt.ylim([-0.2,1.5])

plt.show()
```

This certainly appears to give me the plot I want. However, I want to end up doing stochastic analysis with this set of ODEs, and for that reason, it is much easier to model this if the system of ODEs is written in matrix form (that way, I can easily change the dimension of the noise and see how that affects the ODEs). I understand how mathematically to write the equation in matrix form, but I don't understand how to modify my code so that in the "def model(t,r):" part, it's read as an array/matrix. To convert the equations to matrix form, I can define:

```
b = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]) 
A = np.array([[1, 1+c21, 1-e31, 1-e41], 
              [1-e12, 1, 1+c32, 1+c42],
              [c13+1, 1-e23, 1, 1+c43],
              [c14+1, 1-e24, 1+c34, 1]])
```

And then the system of equations would be (where x is the vector (x1,x2,x3,x4)):

x(t) = diag(x)[b^{T}-Adiag(x)x]

So my question is: How do I modify where I defined my ODEs so that I can enter them as a matrix instead of writing out each equation individually? (this would also make it easier if I later look at a system with more than 4 dimensions)

Comment: What is preventing you from doing exactly as you wrote, replacing `model` with this one line? If I remember correctly, you did this once already. -- Think about replacing the variables x with `u[k]=x[k]^2` or `x[k]=exp(u[k])` for better numerical results.

Comment: @LutzL Because I kept getting errors when I was trying to input. For example:

>    np.array[Eqs[0],Eqs[1],Eqs[2],Eqs[3]].T = np.dot(np.diag(r),b.T-np.dot(np.dot(A,np.diag(r)),np.array[r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]]))

gives me the error: "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Another try: > np.array[Eqs[0],Eqs[1],Eqs[2],Eqs[3]].T = np.dot(np.diag(r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]),b.T-np.dot(np.dot(A,np.diag(r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3])),np.array[r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]]))


Gives me the error: diag() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Comment: @LutzL, I apologize, I can't get the code to appear nicely in the comment section. Are you suggesting the change of variables so that the plots are smoother with less sudden changes so that the integrator has less of a problem plotting them (e.g. I was having problems in odeint but a change of variables may solve that?)

Comment: You could add the more complicated parts of the answer comments as new sections to the question, since it clarifies what you already tried resp. where you want to go with it. -- Please read up on the logic of assignments in computer languages, what you try will not work in non-functional languages, and probably also not in most functional languages. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the implemented preference for `numpy.array` operations to act element-wise (in contrast to `numpy.matrix` operations that operate in matrix fashion) the formula for the system of equations is simply

```
def model(t,x):
    return x*(b-A.dot(x*x))
```

`x*x` produces the vector of element-wise squares, `x**2` would be another option, `A.dot(x2)` performs the matrix-vector product for `numpy.array` objects, and `x*(b-...)` is again the vector-valued element-wise product of the two operand vectors.

---

Using `u=x*x` as variables reduces the system to

```
dotu = 2*u*(b-A.dot(u))
```

thus it has one degree less and is quadratic in `u` which may help in the examination of the stationary points. I suspect that they all are hyperbolic, so that there is no asymptotically stable solution.

---

Using the substitution `u=log(x)` and thus

```
dotu = b-A.dot(exp(2*u))
```

hides the stationary points at minus infinity, thus the analytical value of this substitution may be limited. However, the positivity of `x=exp(u)` is built-in, which may allow for more aggressive numerical methods or provide a bit more accuracy using the same cautiousness as before.

Comment: Ah, that was much easier to put it in matrix form than I thought. I will play around with substitutions and see if I can have better luck this time around with odeint. Thank you!

Comment: I was also trying to do was to add noise to the system. So I tried (setting sigma1 = 0.01): "def model(t,x):
    return x*(b-A.dot(x*x))+sigma1*x*np.random.normal(0,1)" but this fails. I don't get any error messages, just an empty plot. Is there an alternative way to plot the SDE? Usually there's a "dt" part and then the white noise part is on the timescale "sqrt(dt)", but the Euler-Maruyama method plots didn't work (Perhaps the substitutions will fix that, I will look) -- the trajectories seem to stop cycling around after a certain point, so I was hoping there's a way to do it by this method.

Comment: That will definitely not work. The step-size adaptor requires a smooth function to predict the error contribution, random noise is the diametral opposite to that. And the scaling is off, it should be 1/sqrt(dt), but that is impossible to encode this way. There is no better way than Euler-Maruyama that I know off.

Comment: I did the variable reduction to get rid of the quadratic term in hopes that it would smooth out the curve. However, odeint still doesn't seem to like the equation (http://oi63.tinypic.com/25sc2dy.jpg). I coded "def model(m,t): dmdt = 2*np.dot(np.diag(m), b.T - np.dot(A, m)) return dmdt". The log substitution gives problems with errors "cannot convert float NaN to integer." I would think the first substitution should fix things but I'm not sure why odeint still dislikes it (I think it's the parameter choices but the points are all hyperbolic, so it really shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: I had no problem with the log substitution, not that it changed the general quality of the result. I can not see where integer conversion of floats would occur in this ODE.